# Invert undirected graph edge

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a list of edges,

```
 {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}
```

How do I get the 'invert' of the list,

```
 {2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}
```

I'm aware that both these lists will yield the same graph.

Comment: Map `Reverse` like `Reverse /@ list`

Comment: @BenIzd This is not safe when dealing with edge tagged graphs.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing that out. For that case, we could map `SubsetMap[Reverse, ;; 2]`

Comment: @BenIzd Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
UndirectedEdge[#2, #1, ##3] & @@@ edgelist
```

`Reverse` should not be applied to an `UndirectedEdge` as it may have more than two arguments in [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you're not working on `EdgeTaggedGraph`, then you can directly map `Reverse` like below:

```
Reverse /@ edgelist
```

Or with the second argument of `Reverse` (which is faster than mapping and uses less memory):

```
Reverse[edgelist, 2]
```

Or re-order the columns manually:

```
edgelist[[All, {2, 1}]]
```

In the case of `EdgeTaggedGraph` where all the edges are tagged, you can use:

```
edgelist[[All, {2, 1, 3}]]
```

Or generally:

```
SubsetMap[Reverse, ;; 2] /@ edgelist
```

But it's slower (~45 times) and uses more memory in comparison with Szabolcs's answer.